# Blender File getting too large after workflow

Tags: workflow, blend-files, saving, project

i'm currently working on a visualisation for an event company.

They want different spaces to be shown to a pending client. For this purpose i've built a file that i can create all these spaces in, but seeing my geometry grow during this workflow, the file eventually ends up multiple GB big (currently 7.64 GB) which seriously slows down my whole process.

Blender becomes Kind of Laggy, saving also becomes a case of minutes instead of seconds and the whole file becomes kind of crash prone.

i'm wondering if there's a tip or a workaround to this workflow, seeing i still have to get these different spaces together in a scene for a final group assembly.

any tips are welcome!

Comment: You can separate your spaces into several independent files, and link them all into a master file. White the master file will be as laggy as the current one, working on each individual space may be slightly more bearable. Optimize your scene, use instancing instead of arrays, or duplicating things around wherever possible